# Creating web application for first time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, web-applications

I am tasked with creating a web application using HTML 5, CSS3 and JavaScript.( For a study assignment) and I have decided I will be making a web app to record your workouts in regards to weight lifting(As well as thing such as graphs and a counter for days without skipping a workout etc..). But there are a few requirements I have to meet and do not fully understand and would appreciate if anyone could help me with any of these enquires.

1. I need to use in-built cloud storage to ensuring persistence of data through in-built cloud storage. But as I try to create my project to utilize in built cloud storage, I am informed I do not have any subscriptions is there a free alternative to do this, or am I required to obtain a subscription ?.
2. I have also chosen to use ASP.NET MVC template to create my desired application, and was wondering if you consider this the correct choice for the app I wish to create? .
3. I am also required to make use of a library/ libraries external to the application and could use some clarification of if this mean using something such as JQuery etc. or I am just not understanding the requirement correctly. ?.

Sorry for such a long winded post. I look forward and pre thank you for and points you can help clear up for me in advance as well as for any addition tip you think a learner could use in the development if there first web app.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are a student, then you can apply for a dreamspark subscription for Azure.
2. I'm a beginner just like you, and I've used ASP.NET MVC to build my first app.I don't think the framework is an important part in project which is for a study assignment. Just use the one that you like most.
3. There are some packages that I used in my app:

   - Newtonsoft.Json
   - JQuery
   - NInject
   - log4net
   - EntityFramework